# Position while comparing and extracting text

Tags: c#, html, itext

i have extracted the PDF using itextsharp then converted to html for comparison of two PDF for their stlye. in this i added left and top position for alignment of text. But as soon as i receive superscript the position of text changes. But when i check through firebug the position of left and right position is same as i checked using adobe illustrator. can anyone tel me. Why its happening.In the example i have posted the 7 number should come below "was" but it is away from "was"[image]el away from was.

```
Vector curBaseline = renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
Vector topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
y_direction_source = Form1.Pagesize_source +( height_extract_source_page - curBaseline[Vector.I2]);
this.result.AppendFormat("<p style=\"left:{0}pt;top:{1}pt;\">" curBaseline[Vector.I1], y_direction_source);
```

result:

```
<p style="font-family:TimesNewRoman;font-size:12.2618001271429pt;font-weight:;font-style:;left:42pt;top:120.2399pt;position:absolute;">
<p style="background: cyan">training</p>
<p style="background: cyan">camps</p>
<pp style="background: cyan">in</p>
<pp style="background: cyan">Afghanistan</p>
<pp style="background: cyan">.</p>
</p>
<pp style="font-family:TimesNewRoman;font-size:10.2386067682737pt;font-weight:;font-style:;left:441.48pt;top:114.72pt;position:absolute;">
<pp style="background: cyan">7</p>
</p>
```

Comment: Please post code and the PDF in question to make your issue reproducible.

Comment: What code did you use to extract the text? What are the pixel positions given for "was" and "7". What is the output HTML & CSS?

Comment: position of 7 is 441.48pt and y position is 114.72pt

Answer (score 1):

I took your bit of code and opent it in Chrome. The absolute offset of 42 results in a much bigger gap between the dot and the number 7 at my end. Also I had to rearange some of the P's and PP's to get a similair result.

It takes the browser 182 px to write "training camps in Afghanistan ." but the difference in position is about 302 to much at the sample. Looks like 302-42 that the parent has a 260 offset?

My guess based on the code I see here is that the line "training camps in Afghanistan ." is positioned inline in another elemnt, while the 7 is not. That is not the problem, but the extra gap makes providing a sollution harder to do.

On the other hand it also explains why this might be happening. There is no such thing as super- or subscript. To act like there is we scale fonts and have them printed with offsets.
That is no different for the PDF you translate.

As a result the 7 is positioned different and written with a different font size than the rest of the text. Now I don't know how your original PDF works out the details but the effect you see could well be a difference in the margin.

In PDF you can set up a number of different options for the font, like word spacing, or specify a indent level. I would say that your offset of the normal line has a left page margin while the 7 is really placed absolute, or the font used has some special settings, making the sentence longer.

Since you already have Illustrator you could check if not the 7, but the . is placed in the same location. My guess would be it isn't, and the 7 is possitioned correctly. It just looks like the odd one out, but really all the rest of the plain text is positioned differently in your html.

What you could do is have every word positioned absolute, not only the lines.
That would compensate for any differences in fonts, type settigns, browser behavior or other influcences.

Comment: @ ferry remaining text position are as it is in PDF